# Incorrect output when modifying the value from an array to another one

Tags: c++, algorithm, containers, transform

The question is to take a number (`num`), create an array with that many (`num`) elements, and then print an output which gives you an array in which each element is the product of the other elements in the array (excluding the corresponding element)

You'll better understand this with an input/output example:

If the input is:

```
3                // number of elements
4 5 6            // array elements
```

...then the output should be:

```
30 24 20         // 6*5=30, 6*4=24, 4*5=20
```

Currently the output given happens to be incorrect.  I end up getting are garbage values.  I can't seem to figure out what went wrong and where.

```cplusplus
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void mult(int arr[],int num );

int main()
{
    int num,arr[100];

    cin>>num;

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    mult(arr,num);
    return 0; 
}

void mult(int arr[100],int num)
{ 
    int arr2[100];
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        arr2[i]=1;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        {
            for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
            {
                if(j==i)
                {}
                else
                {
                    arr2[i]*=arr[j];
                } 
            } 
        } 

        for(int k=0;k<num;k++)
        {
            cout<<arr2[k]+" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO If I/O is working, just remove that from the question and focus on the algorithm. Otherwise, it just adds more unnecessary complexity and makes it harder to determine the input you're using. Also, this code is barely readable. Please use significant whitespace when posting questions (or when coding in general). Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `cout<<arr2[k]+" ";` or `cout<<arr2[k]<<" ";`?  They do very different things.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is better to use the standard class `std::vector` instead of arrays.

The function should do only one action: to form a new array according to the assignment.

Its output should be done in main.

A general approach can look the following way. At first you should calculate the product of all elements of the original vector and then use this value by to calculate the value of an element of the destination vector simply by dividing the product by the value of the element of the original vector.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done using standard C++ algorithms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 4, 5, 6 };

    for ( const auto &item : v1 ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    int product = std::accumulate( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ), 1, 
                                   std::multiplies<>() );

    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2.reserve( v1.size() );

    std::transform( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ), std::back_inserter( v2 ),
                    [=]( const auto &item ) { return product / item; } );

    for ( const auto &item : v2 ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4 5 6 
30 24 20
```

Use the ideas to write your code.

As for your code then you should the last loop place outside other loops.

```
for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    {
        for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
        {
            if(j==i)
            {}
            else
            {
                arr2[i]*=arr[j];
            } 
        } 
    } 

}

for(int k=0;k<num;k++)
{
    cout<<arr2[k] << " ";
}
```

And at least this code snippet

```
        if(j==i)
        {}
        else
        {
            arr2[i]*=arr[j];
        }
```

it is better to rewrite like

```
        if(j != i)
        {
            arr2[i] *= arr[j];
        }
```

And in this statement

```
cout<<arr2[k]+" ";
            ^^^
```

there is a typo. It is evident that you mean

```
cout<<arr2[k] << " ";
```

Comment: thank you so much for the time you took to explain all that :), I  did mix in a bit of python in that last line and altering that fixed the thing. But I wasn't aware of vectors. Thank you for that piece of information